# Is this expected result in pgr_dijkstra?

Tags: pgrouting, pgr-dijkstra

I have a really dense network of nodes and edges that is based on rasterized version of bathymetric vector data. Every edge has cost which is the distance the edge covers, except in most shallow areas where cost is a bit higher. That's just to explain why the algorithm avoids the blue water in the attached image.

Now as seen in the image, it's not giving me the shortest path, but instead  it first tries to go north and only when it's completed going north it starts proceeding to west. And in the end, once again, it only goes south as soon as it's completed going west.

Red lines are in my opinion closer to the expected result.

The question is: Is this how pgr_dijkstra is expected to work? Or am I doing something wrong when using the function, or while creating the network?

[image: example result]

Comment: Can you also add the vector graph you used with your pgr_djikstra and the sql command ? Because I suspect that you are not working on the graph you think. Check reverse cost and how edge are connected